# SWIFTUI: Can't dismiss Sheet after changing ScreenSize classes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I toggle a sheet in SwiftUI with the following Button

```swift
Button(action: {
                    self.statusPopoverIsShown.toggle()
                })
```

So the following sheet appears

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: self.$popoverIsShown) {
                    RandomSheet(popoverIsShown: self.$popoverIsShown)
}
```

Then I have a button inside the `RandomSheet`to dismiss the sheet (sets the popoverIsShown to false). Everything works fine.

But when I start using the app in splitscreen or somehow change the sizeclass SwiftUI transforms the sheet to a fullscreen iPhone-like sheet and the dismiss button/the binding does not work anymore.

Is there any solution to avoid this and keep the binding stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with any size class changes. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct TestSheet: View {
    @State private var popoverIsShown = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            self.popoverIsShown = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$popoverIsShown) {
            RandomSheet(popoverIsShown: self.$popoverIsShown)
        }
    }
}

struct RandomSheet: View {
    @Binding var popoverIsShown: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Close") { self.popoverIsShown = false }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's basically what I did before, but does it work on iOS 14 when you open the sheet, resize the view and then try to dismiss?

Comment: Yes, exactly that was tested.

Comment: okay great, unfortunately i can't test it right now because i don't have access to a iOS 14 device or xcode12. So i assume it was an iOS 13 bug. thanks for your help

Comment: I am having the same issue, and unfortunately this solution does not work for me.  I have taken code from Apples sample app Fruta, so that my ContentView changes from a tab navigation to a sidebar navigation hierarchy after a horizontalSizeClass change.  When my sheet is presented and I change size class, the binding breaks, and so setting it to false has no effect.